# As a student with basic understanding on Java can I switch to Android?

Tags: java, android

My friend says I should pick up the Android App Development for Dummies and I'll be fine, just learn as I go [[http://www.amazon.com/Android-Application-Development-For-Dummies/dp/1118387104/ref=pd_sim_b_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=15GHNG7MTDPPEX6JFEC5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118387104) ]

I don't want to waste time learning any concepts related to web development/GUI with Java and want to learn Android instead, but I feel concerned with my lack of comprehensive knowledge on Java so I would like an answer from a broader community of Android/Java developers.

For context; I've already learned:

- OOP Concept, Variables, Methods, Classes, Objects, Constructors, 
  Interfaces, Abstract Classes, Control Structures i.e. loops and
  branches

I have NOT learned:

ArrayLists,
Threading, 
Map / Hash, 
GUI / Swings, etc

What do you guys think?

Comment: You can switch at any moment. Just prepare to do some more effort: `ArrayLists, Threading, Map / Hash, GUI / Swings, etc`... Google, Google, Google, StackOverflow - Google, Google, Google, StackOverflow - ...

Comment: I'm not a professional myself but I would just say: Give it a try. There a tons of videos and tutorials about Android out there..

And if you then don't understand a thing from the beginning you should learn Java first.

Comment: I remember when I learned Android, I made a simple calculator app. It helps you to understand the basics (how the layout works, etc.) with a simple logic. So you should go with something enough basic not too hard and you will learn step by step!

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion is that if you switch to Android too early, that might slow down your progress. Programming Java on a PC is more transparent, and it is still easier to find solutions to common issues regarding it on the internet. ArrayLists, multithreading and HashMaps are very basic and necessary tools, you will not go far without them, and it will be faster to learn them first on PC and then more painlessly and quickly switch to Android, in my opinion.

Comment: +1: Desktop Java is also easier to debug. But Android apps can be more rewarding, and therefore motivate people more. Some people are satisfied with a command line application, some aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.
Sometimes even a simplest application needs more that you have right now,
but while knowing a little more you can build simple applications
and you will need to learn a lot about Android itself.

http://developer.android.com is an excellent place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can.But I would suggest you to learn a bit about basics of GUI and some other java concepts and then move onto android.It wont take long.But even without learning it,with much more effort you can move onto it.You can take help from these reference websites:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html

http://developer.android.com

Books:

Hello Android

Professional Android 4 Application Development